# Dúvida sobre o uso do static

Tags: c++, c++11

Código:

Header:

```
class Cliente
{
public:
    Cliente(std::string nome_c, int num_cartao_l, int livros_c);
    Cliente();

    void calc_Taxa();

    const int get_livros() const { return livros; }
    const std::string get_nome() const { return nome; }
    const int get_cartao() const { return num_cartao; }
    const double get_taxa() const { return taxa; }

private:
    int livros;
    std::string nome;
    int num_cartao;  // numero do cartão do cliente
    double taxa;
};

void const cliente_divida();
```

Cpp:

```
Cliente::Cliente(string nome_c, int num_cartao_l, int livros_c)
    :nome(nome_c), num_cartao(num_cartao_l), livros(livros_c)
{
    if (livros < 0) cout << "Livros não podem ser negativos, por favor reinicie o programa." << endl;
}

Cliente default_cliente()
{
    Cliente def("Fulano", 000, 0);
    return def;
}

Cliente::Cliente()
    :nome(default_cliente().nome),
    num_cartao(default_cliente().num_cartao),
    livros(default_cliente().livros)
{
}

void Cliente::calc_Taxa()
{
    taxa = livros * 4; // a taxa é de 4 dólares/reais
}

const void cliente_divida()
{

    if (Cliente::get_taxa() == 0)
    {
        cout << "Cliente não possui dividas." << endl;
    }
    else cout << "Cliente possui uma divida de" << Cliente::get_taxa() << " dolares." << endl;

}
```

Não possuo nada na main ainda.

Enfim, a dúvida está em `const void cliente_divida()`, eu não posso chamar o membro da classe sem antes ter declarado um objeto, mas no caso eu preciso usar a taxa exatamente do atual objeto da main. Isso seria o trabalho para um ponteiro ou algum método `static` que me permitiria chamar o membro sem instanciar o objeto. Eu tentei transformar a função `get_taxa()` em `static` e a `taxa` em `static` também mas recebi um `unresolved external symbol`. Gostaria de saber um método limpo para a resolução.

OBS: Para melhor interpretação, considere que é um programa para clientes de bibliotecas.

Comment: Talvez fosse interessante por o `main()`, o `get_ taxa()`, mostrar melhor o que deseja, ou seja fazer um [mcve].

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com: "mas no caso eu preciso usar a taxa exatamente do atual **objeto da main.**"? De qualquer forma, como vc sabe que o cliente tá em dívida se vc não quer instanciá-lo? pq é isso que o comando `Cliente::get_taxa()` tá dizendo

Comment: Opa, resolvi instanciando um objeto na função com o ponteiro `&`, o `get_taxa()` era literalmente só aquilo mesmo e o meu `main()` era um escopo main vazio. De qualquer forma, obrigado.

Comment: `const void` caramba nunca tinha visto isso antes o0 é proposital?

Answer (score 1):

Sua função cliente_divida pode receber como parâmetro uma instancia de cliente, assim outra parte do código ficaria responsável por instanciar o cliente e chamar a função cliente_divida.